# Problems building report-viewer in ms-hosted build server

Tags: build, azure-pipelines, reportviewer, visual-studio-2019

I have been upgrading to vs-2019 and the 2016 version of report viewer and do now get a problem when building in the ms-hosted azure pipelines. Same problem does not occur building and testing in my local environment using visual studio.

I have upgraded from .net framework 4.7 to 4.7.2 as I have read that the azure build server vs2019 uses 4.7.2 but this apparently does not solve the problem.

I have upgraded packages Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms to the latest version 150.1358.0
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to the latest version 14.0.1016.290

I get these errormessages when building

### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4552,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "d:\a\1\s\SsegukuReports\SqlServerTypes\x86\msvcr120.dll" because it was not found.

### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4552,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "d:\a\1\s\SsegukuReports\SqlServerTypes\x64\SqlServerSpatial140.dll" because it was not found.

### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4552,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "d:\a\1\s\SsegukuReports\SqlServerTypes\x86\SqlServerSpatial140.dll" because it was not found.

### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4552,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "d:\a\1\s\SsegukuReports\SqlServerTypes\x64\msvcr120.dll" because it was not found.

Answer (score 7):

> Problems building report-viewer in ms-hosted build server

If you installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Types via NuGet and your application works locally but you get errors when building via Azure DevOps then you simply **need to add the dlls to source control**.

[image]

Note:

These dlls are ignored (red icon at left) by default. Right-click the ignored dlls and select Add Ignored File to Source Control… then commit and push your changes.

Hope this helps.